# foreach - return the highest value

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach, isset

I have a foreach loop in php.

Loop will return 4 diffirent values and i want to display the highest from it.

Specifically, my loop will return array with date and temperature for that day.

The example code for indication:

```
foreach ($variable as $key => $value) {
    $temperature = temprature();
    $date = date();

    $teploty[$date] = $teplota;

    if(!isset($teploty[$date]) > -50) {
      $teploty[$date] = $teplota;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try to specify your question more! Because i don't get what you want! (I starring at the screen and do not understand the question!)

Comment: That foreach loop doesn't really make much sense? You aren't using the $key / $value pair in it? More info please?

Comment: A loop itself can not return a value. Are you running it from a method/function call?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is confusing.  This is how you find the highest value in an array of numbers:

```
$highest = null;
foreach ($numbers as $num) {
    if (is_null($highest) || $num > $highest) {
        $highest = $num;
    }
}
```

You should be able to adapt this pattern to your code and data.